# Notepad++ Reformat lines in a text file to command line arguments line -k "line1" -k "line2" -k "line3"?

Tags: notepad++

so I have big text file that is like so:

```
Aids
Cancer
Heart Disease
Dwarfism
Coranavirus
```

and essentially, I need to convert this so that my command line script can read these as arguments. The format is -k "keyword" and especially I need to use Notepad++ to reformat it like so -k "Aids" -k "Cancer" -k "Heart Disease" -k "Dwarfism" -k "Coranavirus"

How can I do this exactly?

I have tried using ^ and \1 expressions to put the -k " in front and replace, but I'm not sure what expression I need to do exactly to get them all on the same line.

Help is appreciated. Happy Easter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)\R`
- Replace with: `-k "$1"`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(.+)        # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Replacement:**

```
-k          # literally -k followed by a space
"$1"        # content of group 1 suround by quotes followed by a space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]